# Component required to detect change of length

Tags: sensor

I am looking for a means to measure the length of a ca. 1 m long metal bar. Due to temperature changes it will expand and contract, and I want to be able to compensate for that electronically, say once per second or thereabouts.

So I don't need an actual measurement of length, I just need to know if it is over or under length, ideally with a precision of ca. 0.1 mm. Obviously, I need care in how to mount such a sensor, but that is a separate issue, and rather dependant on how the measuring tool works!

Comment: @All - The long comment chain has included partial answers and also exceeded what is reasonable in comments. Therefore it has been moved to chat and should be continued there (link below). -- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here might be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat now, please!** Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138898/discussion-on-question-by-mike-brockington-component-required-to-detect-change-o).

Answer (score 12):

You can get inexpensive glass linear scales with adequate 5um resolution (1um for a bit more). They have an incremental quadrature TTL output, so easily read with an MCU, Arduino etc. If incremental output is okay for you this is one way to get there. Note that you would reset the count at power up and it will detect *changes* from that initial position, not an absolute measurement of length.

Although you can get long scales, over 1m, the scales themselves, even very expensive ones, tend to have CTE similar to most metals, of the order of \$10^{-5}\$/°C. So you could buy a short scale, mount it on (readout centered between mounting points) on a 19mm diameter Invar bar and take that out of the equation.

[Here](https://amzn.to/3PX5atM) is a typical short scale (150mm). No idea of the reliability of this particular supplier, do your due diligence.

[image]

Comment: I had no idea this sort of sensor existed, very cool!

Comment: Or just make the pendulum out of an invar bar...

Comment: @mkeith Missed that OP disclosed the actual application. https://cityspecialmetals.com/invar-uses-clock-pendulums/

Comment: Invar is quite specifically NOT the answer to this question, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Calculating Δlength instead of measuring it directly seems easier and cheaper.

If size and material of the bar are known (or at least constant across a production run) and the bar's temperature can be measured (in one or more places), you should be able to calculate the bar's change in length accurately and easily.

The sensors will be relatively cheap, no length reference or extra mechanical mounting is needed, and a-linearities can be taken care of in software.

Comment: The simple answer is that no, I can't accurately measure the temperature, hence part of the reason why I wanted to do direct measurement.

Answer (score 7):

> *I am looking for a means to measure the length of a ca. 1 m long metal
> bar.*

The good old fashioned way of detecting movement changes was using a dial-test-indicator (DTI). Nowadays you can get them with a data output: -

[image]

I believe some of them use Bluetooth for data transmission.

> *ideally with a precision of ca. 0.1 mm*

The one above has a resolution of 0.01 mm.

Comment: Interesting thought, any idea how this works internally - makes more sense to replicate that, in my case.

Comment: @MikeBrockington they have been around since probably before the 20th century and I'm sure you can find something on google that will provide an answer. It's fundamentally mechanical in nature so, how it works internally is off-topic.

Comment: That's a dial indicator, not a DTI. A DTI looks like  [this](https://i.imgur.com/PGFAhrf.png)

Comment: @MikeBrockington just some gears and linkages I believe - it literally just translates the distance the tip moves, into the rotation of a dial. Not sure how the indicator responds to itself expanding. Maybe the internals are made of invar.

Comment: @user253751 old school ones had a rack and gears (jeweled movements on good ones) and hairsprings to drive the needle. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/pWI3Q07.jpg)  is what a (low cost) modern digital one looks like. It's just a different style of the capacitive incremental circuit used in digital calipers with a very simple mechanism. There's nothing exotic like Invar in these at all, brass, steel and pot metal.

Comment: How would you mount this so it can measure the absolute length, not just relative to some frame which could itself expand/contract?  The OP mentioned in comments (unfortunately not the question itself) that they're trying to avoid invar or other materials with low temperature coefficients of expansion.

Comment: @PeterCordes the question was this *So I don't need an actual measurement of length, I just need to know if it is over or under length, ideally with a precision of ca. 0.1 mm* <-- in other words the solution I offered is not for measuring absolute length.

Comment: Right, ok, but you have to mount this somewhere.  What I meant to say was that it requires an expansion-free frame to be able to accurately detect changes in the length of the bar itself.  If the frame and bar expand with temperature at similar rates, and stay at similar temps, this might measure negligible deflection even if the bar elongates by a few tenths of mm.  Your answer doesn't say anything about solving that problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes this is an EE site and not a mechanical engineering site so I'm not going to speculate on what materials the OP likely has to hand nor what his skills are in that respect. I'm offering an idea that he can choose to use or not use. Ask him if you are interested.

Answer (score 4):

Measure or "cutting" ...

> just need to know if it is over or under length, ideally with a precision of c. 0.1mm .

I would use primary a fixed "microscope" if I could place the bar against a stop on one side.
When done, I would use an [LVDT sensor](https://www.ni.com/en-us/innovations/white-papers/06/measuring-position-and-displacement-with-lvdts.html#:%7E:text=An%20LVDT%20measures%20displacement%20by,back%20to%20the%20secondary%20windings.) device with calibration (if the bar is well "terminated").  Obviously, you need however a "reference".

[image]

Or something as [this](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Digital-Caliper-Vernier-Micrometer-Electronic-Ruler-Gauge-Meter-Measuring-Tool-Carbon-Fiber-Caliper/395090806)

Comment: See this https://www.befr.ebay.be/itm/402221461033?hash=item5da6446e29:g:45kAAOSwmyhhC1fi&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAsI06Zx0Y56QDn5U15xnEC%2FhiE%2Bgaox0Wseal%2BxClJYN2Yq0ZtegRth4ygt5zxJd6%2BJDkBEzERJxuDFg1elypyIya6wrYEEJGXihufYsS8OoURStpxHf%2BnT%2FbpdCnORI0JIl%2FRszVA%2FafGBhMp1XUVAYg%2BeK%2FmEirU1sH9%2FhQFGcO05S9ybztYyZnzuCRtYezL1FvcKHORKUcDTkJixH91R35WxS85mmPMxRMFyrRfq47%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR5Tn66bdYA

Answer (score 3):

In principle I would use a sheet of glass as a reference plane and mount one end of the bar securely to the glass. At the other end I would mount transmission gratings, one on the bar and the other on the glass, and count Moire fringes as the bar changes length.

Comment: Very nice idea. But how would you count the fringes electronically?

Comment: Optically - a focussed light source and a photodetector; more specifically, two such detectors in quadrature to determine direction as well as count, driving an up/down counter system. The main snag is that this only detects changes in length, so how a reference is set becomes a problem unless the system is powered continuously.

Comment: It would indeed be powered (mostly) continuously, but I agree that calibration would be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

For pendulum applications where temperature-induced length changes are of concern, you need to be measuring atmospheric pressure and temperature anyway to do corrections related to air damping. If the environment is a confined space where significant changes to air composition are possible, you'll need a gas analyzer too.

So, you already should have a solid ambient air temperature measurement. From that you derive the length of the rod. You can also instrument the rod with a 4-wire Pt-100 temperature sensor. I've seen it done using 4 rods in parallel, each used as a conductor, with the Pt-100 sensor mounted on one of them, with tiny wires connecting it to the other rods.

But in any case, the temperature is an excellent proxy for thermal expansion. You can characterize the pendulum beam for thermal mass and thermal resistance to ambient air, to compensate for dT/dt at least to the first order.

If the rod is long *and* significantly loaded by the pendulum weight, then you'll also be making non-linear corrections due to dynamic stretching of the rod (centripetal force it exerts on the weight).

So, I'd say - if you have to worry about temperature, then you have to worry about all that other stuff too, since it all falls within an order of magnitude of each other, design-dependent of course.

> It will be a pendulum.

Is this for a museum display or an educational demo? I'm at a bit of a loss as to what one would use a pendulum for in a professional capacity otherwise...

But in any case: all this seems like a problem for a metrologist. The electrical engineering end of things is the simplest. A proper metrological error analysis will inform what you must measure, and how to best measure it using measurement devices available.

The question to be off-topic here, since without a metrological analysis to substantiate that you absolutely must measure physical length and nothing else will do... it's a classic XY problem. I would go as far as saying that a proper analysis will tell you that you **do not** need to measure the actual length of the rod.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the question - the way to avoid all that temperature and pressure measurement and calculation, is to directly measure the length of the pendulum... That needs to be done 'continually' which makes it an electronics issue. The physical side of things is indeed off-topic, which is why I have said very little about it.

Answer (score 2):

Use an optical distance measurement sensor in the axis of the bar.

Option 1, if the end of the bar is in the open:

```
===================   <|
bar                   sensor pointed towards end of bar
```

Option 2, if you can't have anything in the axis of the bar:

```
                   |  <|  sensor pointed towards sheet at end of bar
===================|=============== 
bar                ^  
                   |
              metal sheet at the end of the bar
```

In option 2, you could also measure from the start of the bar, but usually the shorter the distance the better the accuracy.

Many sensors have specs suggesting very poor accuracy, but [some users](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/21678/6934) seem to have obtained sub-mm accuracy. There are a few more suggestions in that page.

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible to determine the length of the bar by striking it and measuring the dominant resonant frequency, which should decrease with an increase in length. It may also be possible to apply sound waves by means of a loudspeaker or other audio device, and determine the frequency of resonance. Along the same lines of thought, perhaps a form of time domain reflectometry could be used, where a pulse could be applied to one end of the bar and the time to receive a reflected pulse from the other end could determine its length.

However, from what I have read, the frequency of a tuning fork's change with temperature is more dependent upon changes in Young's modulus, and that varies greatly with type of material. But even if the change in pitch (or time of reflected pulse) is determined by temperature, it should still be possible to further correlate that to length if the coefficient of expansion is known.

Some information:

https://cpb-ap-se2.wpmucdn.com/learn.stleonards.vic.edu.au/dist/5/110/files/2012/08/temperature-tuning-fork-annotated.pdf

http://www.isjos.org/JoP/vol5iss1/Papers/JoPv5i1-3TuningFork.pdf

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60339/frequency-of-a-tuning-fork

[https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~tymerski/ece331/Lab2_TDR_331.pdf](https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/%7Etymerski/ece331/Lab2_TDR_331.pdf)

Comment: The tuning-fork idea is a very cool suggestion indeed. The TDR idea sounds rather more promising - anyone heard of a component-level method of achieving it - I've only ever seen TDR as an entire machine.

Answer (score 2):

A change of length of 0.1mm over 1000mm means a strain of 1e-4. That is well within the capabilities of a **strain gauge**. The large advantage of a strain gauge is that you do not need a separate stable mounting location.

The principal disadvantage is that you are doing a relative measurement, so you will need some information about the beam beforehand. Furthermore, if used incorrectly, the strain gauge temperature will affect the measurement. To get accurate readings, consider three- or four wire strain gauges in some bridge configuration. Beam bending can be cancelled in the measurement by using strain gauges on opposing sides of the beam.

Accuracy is limited by the electronic circuit driving and reading the gauges, but off-the-shelf equipment is readily available that should work well enough for your application.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not what you asked. But in order to measure the length of a 1 meter rod, you will probably need to use a 1 meter rod made out of a material that has a low or zero coefficient of thermal expansion (CTE). If you have a 1 meter rod made from a material with a low or zero CTE, then the easier thing is to just use it as the pendulum in the first place and skip the measurements.

Possible materials are invar and graphite fiber reinforced plastic. The CTE of invar over the range 0 to 100 C is about 1.2 ppm / K. You are trying to achieve a measurement accuracy of 0.1mm. That is about 100 ppm in a 1 meter bar. So this seems feasible. The 1 meter invar rod will increase in length by about 0.1 mm as it is heated from 0 C to 80 C.

If you don't use something like this, you will find, upon analysis, that you are at the mercy of some other CTE, such as the CTE of the material to which you mount your laser or other apparatus. The entire room housing your pendulum will have a CTE, so mounting a remote sensor introduces a leg between the remote sensor and pendulum that is subject to thermal expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts - I think you are only half correct though. If I know that the co-efficient of expansion of the 'rig' is significantly different to that of the bar itself, then I still get a differential, which might be good enough.

Comment: I mean, yeah, I guess. But then again, all you really need to do is measure the temperature of the reference rod (you are already assuming it is at the same temperature as the pendulum rod). So I guess that is another end-run around the apparatus tempco thing.